# Tracking vectors in 3D

Tags: 3d

A 3D object with smooth surface is given as in the figure. There exist two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ on different points on the surface. These vectors represent velocity vectors on different moments in time. I have many of these vectors distributed over the surface and interested in whether they are members of the trajectory of a moving obhject. We do not have any information about this movement, but roughly, I expect sort of a directional "coherence" between neihgboring vectors if they are parts of the same trajectory. This coherence can be defined as pointing towards the same direction on the surface with some small deviations. How can I concretely quantify this directional coherence? In most of the cases,  $v_1$ and $v_2$ are quite close each other (in space), so I can directly compare them by cosine similarity. But, this approach fails on the edges of less smooth regions. Please note that, the object is not necessarily a sphere. Also, I possess surface normals for each point on the surface.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Graph

What you could do is to construct a graph where you give a certain cost to put v1 and v2 as consecutive segments of the trajectory.

Then to each edge you assign a weight that depending on the velocities, and the positions where those are measured.

Finally you compute the shortest path.

#### Particle simulation

You could parameterize your surface, create a mesh and then you assume a velocity field to be the interpolation on the mesh and you simulate the particle movement.

You can model something similar to a particle in a fluidized bed.
The velocity field are the velocity of currents that are producing a force on your particle, so the particle tends to accelerate to the velocity of the field, but will do so smoothly. You can control the smoothness of the trajectory by the ratio between mass and fluid viscosity.

Comment: Thanks! The graph-based approach seems promising. However, to be able to define costs between neighboring vectors, I need to be able to quantify the similarity of their directions. And this similarity is what I am looking for- especially the surface is not flat.